# Delete the Opposite of a SELECT query with a GROUP BY clause om MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a lengthy SELECT query in MS Access.  I would like to basically DELETE everything from the table that is not selected by the query.  Thank you!

```
    SELECT [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].BENEFIT_PERIOD, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].BENEFIT_TYPE, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].CARRIER_NAME, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].PLAN_NAME, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].PERSON_TYPE, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].LAST_NAME, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].FIRST_NAME, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].MIDDLE_NAME, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].SUFFIX, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].GENDER, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].DATE_OF_BIRTH, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].DATE_OF_HIRE, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].EFFECTIVE_DATE, 
        Max([Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].END_DATE) AS MaxOfEND_DATE, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].SSN

FROM [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report]

GROUP BY [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].BENEFIT_PERIOD, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].BENEFIT_TYPE, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].CARRIER_NAME, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].PLAN_NAME, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].PERSON_TYPE, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].LAST_NAME, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].FIRST_NAME, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].MIDDLE_NAME, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].SUFFIX, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].GENDER, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].DATE_OF_BIRTH, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].DATE_OF_HIRE, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].EFFECTIVE_DATE, 
        [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].SSN;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
delete from [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report]
    where END_DATE < (select max(brdr2.End_Date)
                      from [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report] as brcr2
                      where brcr2.SSN = [Benefit Refused Cancellation Report].SSN
                     );
```

This assumes that the `SSN` uniquely defines each row that you want one row of.  To really match the `GROUP BY`, you need to include more of the fields -- or even all of them.

One caveat:  This doesn't account for `NULL` values, so the keys used for matching should be non-`NULL`.